# Centering an Arabic Section Number Above Justified Title Text

Tags: luatex, titles, titlesec, section-titles, justification

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
I would like to center the Arabic section number above the section title; Moreover, I would like to both left and right justify the title text---with the last line being perfectly centered.}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

*Remark:* For some reason, the command `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%` seems to have no effect here.

QUESTION: How may I center the Arabic section number atop the title (which I would like to be both left and right justified---with the last line being centered)? I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `display` style and, of course, to add the formatting instructions to the `\titleformat` code, not to the section title.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\filcenter\thesection}
  {1ex}
  {\justifycenter}
\newcommand{\justifycenter}[1]{%
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil
  #1%
}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{I would like to center the Arabic section number above the section title; 
  Moreover, I would like to both left and right justify the title text---with the 
  last line being perfectly centered.}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg.