# Difference Between Break and Linebreak Commands

Tags: macros, line-breaking, titlesec, section-titles, badness

The motivation for this question originates from the answer given to [Centering an Arabic Section Number Above Justified Title Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651431/centering-an-arabic-section-number-above-justified-title-text)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\filcenter\thesection}
  {1.25ex}
  {\justifycenter}
\newcommand{\justifycenter}[1]{%
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil
  #1%
}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}

\begin{document}
\large
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Section Title on Which I Would Like to Employ the Linebreak Command; When I Do, Although the\break Output is Correct, I Receive an Error Message.\break However, No Such Error Message Results When I Use the Break Command.}
\end{document}
```

which produces the desired output

[image]

In the code, I make use of the `\break` command in order produce a break in the line without losing the desired justification. I normally would use `\linebreak`, but for some reason unbenownst to me, it produced the desired result---though always with a series of error messages. Again, strangely, the command seemed to work, but not without a display of error messages.

After searching this site for an alternative to the `\linebreak` command, I came across the `\break` command---and it seems to work fine---no error messages.

QUESTION: In ordinary circumstances, is there any reason to prefer `\break` over `\linebreak` (or visa-versa)? Do they both do the same thing? After reading some comments pertaining to the use of `\linebreak`, it gave me the impression that one should use `\linebreak` it as little as possible, though I don't recall any specific reasons being given. What kinds of ``badness'' can be expected with the use of `\linebreak`? Do the same apply to `\break`?

Thank you.

Comment: \break comes from plain and shouldn't be used in latex it is same as linebreak or pagebreak this is a dup, I'll find old answer....

Comment: probably \protect\linebreak or better use opt argument of section to put smaller title in table of contents

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94220/1090

Comment: Also, don't ignore error messages.

Comment: in a current latex `\linebreak` is robust and I get no errors from your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I just updated the linked answer for post 2019 formats.

Comment: Note (again:-) the advice is to avoid forced linebreaking and avoid formatting in section commands, not to avoid the specific command `\linebreak` The argument is used in the section head, the page head and the table of contents and you probably do not want the same break in all three. Hence "moving argument" If you get fragile command in moving argument errors, use `\protect`, or better, update your latex as `\linebreak` has not been fragile since the 2019 release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The question linked is about `\nolinebreak` while this one is about  `\linebreak`, so, although the issues are similar, I don't consider this question a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: @user202729 Seems the questioner did not intend to ignore error-messages, (s)he just did not have a clue what error-messages noticed are about.

Comment: @UlrichDiez you do know that they share  almost all their code and just differ by a  `-`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You know and I know, but a novice asking questions most likely does not know.

Comment: sure but questions about subsections get closed as dup of questions about sections, and questions about any missing % get closed as dup of a question about % at eol. and this is far closer. But democracy at work, vote to re-open and if 4 people agree feel free to answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I won't - your clarification is sufficient. ;-)